# How many values a slicer can hold?

Tags: powerbi, dax, dashboard, powerquery, slicers

In power bi how many values a slicer and hierarchy slicer visual can hold.Recently in one of the dashboard i used a hierarchy slicer for one field , where field contains 169k distinct values. Problem is slicer is not show all values and performance wise it is slow

Thanks,
B

Comment: How on earth do you expect users to pick from 169,000 distinct values?!

Comment: I don't know what the slicer's technical limitation for number of elements is, but I'm confident that it well exceeds the practical needs of any user.  I think you need to revisit your design and provide a more navigable report.  A slicer with 20 elements is starting to be unwieldy.

Comment: @Olly - Thanks for reply , i gave simialr answer to the User . But  i just want to know   how many values can slicers can handle .

Comment: @Ryan - Thanks for your reply . we are POC stage  so try to find how many values it can hold .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about this visual:  "Hierarchy Slicer" from App Source

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380820?mktcmpid=Pickitli&tab=Overview

[image]

Understand that 'number of rows/items' is rarely a specified limit in PowerBI.  The limiting factor is the memory of the machine running the report.  At some point, things just slow down past usability.